# Sortable list numbers are not showing in order while dragging (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following `jQuery\Javascript\HTML` code for a sortable list, and it works fine, except while dragging the wrong numbers display. For example, when dragging character2 to the character1 slot, the number '3' is displayed. Does anyone know why this is and how to fix it? I have also included a Stack Snippet now so you can see what happens...

```js
function menuClicked(menuId) {
  switch (menuId) {
    case "formation":
      document.getElementById("storybox").innerHTML = "<h1>Formation</h1><h2>Drag characters to change positions</h2><ol class='sortable' id='charlist'><li><h3 class='charname'>Dragon-Bear</h3></li><li><h3 class='charname'>Deer-Wolf</h3></li></ol>";
      $(function() {
        $(".sortable").sortable();
        $(".sortable").disableSelection();
      });
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.charname:hover   {
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/js/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li id="ChangeFormation" onclick="menuClicked('formation')">
    <a href="#formation">Change Formation</a>
    <div id="storybox"></div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Could you please put this in a working (in-post preferably) snippet?

Comment: working code at http://orderofthemouse.co.uk , if you click on ```Party``` then ```Change Formation``` – added the ```HTML``` that calls the ```JavaScript``` too.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? and your javascript has errors last 2 semi colons are not required

Comment: I still don't understand where do you use `.sortable()` in your website?

Comment: Yeah, I'm never sure about semi-colons in Javascript after curly brackets so I generally just stick them in anyway.  Does it cause any problems to do that? It always seems to compile ok, I think...

Comment: It's not working atm as I just refactored and I need to implement a callback. I'll put together a stack snippet once I'll got myself some coffee...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Kaivosukeltaja pointed out, the sortable plugin adds a placeholder `li` element with the CSS rule `visibility: hidden`. If you set the `display` of the element to `none`, it obviously won't be taken into consideration, and the numbering will work as expected. However, this defeats the entire point of having a placeholder element (because now, nothing will occupy the space of the element that is currently being dragged).

```
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```js
function menuClicked(menuId) {
  switch (menuId) {
    case "formation":
      document.getElementById("storybox").innerHTML = "<h1>Formation</h1><h2>Drag characters to change positions</h2><ol class='sortable' id='charlist'><li><h3 class='charname'>Dragon-Bear</h3></li><li><h3 class='charname'>Deer-Wolf</h3></li></ol>";
      $(function() {
        $(".sortable").sortable();
        $(".sortable").disableSelection();
      });
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.charname:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/js/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li id="ChangeFormation" onclick="menuClicked('formation')">
    <a href="#formation">Change Formation</a>
    <div id="storybox"></div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

If that's a problem, the better solution would be to remove the default numbering, and use [CSS3 counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) to exclude the placeholder element.

Here is a simple example using CSS3 counters that removes the default numbers using `list-style: none`, and then uses the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) to exclude the `.ui-sortable-placeholder` element from the numbering incrementing.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
}
ol li:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder) {
  counter-increment: number;
}
ol li:before {
  content: counter(number)'. ';
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li class="ui-sortable-placeholder">two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ol>
```

In your case, you could use the following:

```js
function menuClicked(menuId) {
  switch (menuId) {
    case "formation":
      document.getElementById("storybox").innerHTML = "<h1>Formation</h1><h2>Drag characters to change positions</h2><ol class='sortable' id='charlist'><li><h3 class='charname'>Dragon-Bear</h3></li><li><h3 class='charname'>Deer-Wolf</h3></li></ol>";
      $(function() {
        $(".sortable").sortable();
        $(".sortable").disableSelection();
      });
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.charname:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.ui-sortable {
  list-style: none;
}
.ui-sortable > li:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder) {
  counter-increment: number;
}
.ui-sortable > li:before {
  content: counter(number)'. ';
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.ui-sortable h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/js/vendor/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.orderofthemouse.co.uk/js/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li id="ChangeFormation" onclick="menuClicked('formation')">
    <a href="#formation">Change Formation</a>
    <div id="storybox"></div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

```
.ui-sortable {
  list-style: none;
}
.ui-sortable > li:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder) {
  counter-increment: number;
}
.ui-sortable > li:before {
  content: counter(number)'. ';
}
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's **Sortable** plugin works by creating an extra `<li>` element that acts as a placeholder for the dragged item's new position. That will be counted by the browser, causing the number to increment even though the element is set to `visibility: hidden`.

There doesn't seem to be a way to omit `<ol>` numbers using CSS, so the best way to fix this would probably be to hide the list's native numbers and calculate them yourself, updating the numbers on the sortable's `update` event.

Comment: Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but how would one hide the native numbers?

Comment: That's not a stupid question. Set `list-style-type: none`. :)